# PostgreSQL sum some values together and don't for other

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    sum(o.amount),
    t.parent_id
FROM tab t
         LEFT JOIN order o ON o.deal = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

**Current output:**

| id | sum | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 10 |  |
| 3 | 15 | 5 |
| 4 | 30 | 5 |
| 5 | 0 |  |
| 6 | 0 | 8 |
| 7 | 0 | 8 |
| 8 | 20 |  |

Desired logic, if the row contains parent_id then skip it but add everything together in the sum field so for id 3,4,5 the total would be 45 and only the id 5 would be shown. There can be cases when the sums are in the "sub tabs" or in the "main tab" but everything should be summed together.
**Desired output:**

| id | sum | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 10 |  |
| 5 | 45 |  |
| 8 | 20 |  |

What have I tried so far is to do sub-selects and played around with group by. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use coalesce().

```sql
with the_data(id, sum, parent_id) as (
values
    (1, 10, null),
    (2, 10, null),
    (3, 15, 5),
    (4, 30, 5),
    (5, 0, null),
    (6, 0, 8),
    (7, 0, 8),
    (8, 20, null)
)

select coalesce(parent_id, id) as id, sum(sum)
from the_data
group by 1
order by 1
```

Read about the feature [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6836fad45bcb1610c07d391f99eb2abe)

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't valid in PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT
    t.id,
    sum(o.amount),
    t.parent_id
FROM tab t
         LEFT JOIN order o ON o.deal = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Unlike MySQL, PostgreSQL doesn't have implicit `GROUP BY` columns (unless something changed recently).

Anyway, if you're using `t.id` in your `GROUP BY` clause, then each `t.id` will produce one row, so you'll always have 3 and 4 separated, for example.

It looks like you're trying to use the `parent_id` as the main criterion to group by, falling back on the `id` when the `parent_id` is `NULL`.

You could use `COALESCE(t.parent_id, t.id)` to get this value for each row, and then group using it.

For example:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.parent_id, t.id),
    SUM(o.amount)
FROM tab t
         LEFT JOIN order o ON o.deal = t.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.parent_id, t.id)
```

Comment: SELECT
    COALESCE(t.parent_id, t.id),
    SUM(o.amount),
    t.timestamp
FROM tab t
         LEFT JOIN order o ON o.deal = t.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.parent_id, t.id), t.timestamp
What about if there is a timestamp as well which then breaks them apart because its needed to put into the group by

Comment: Could I take only the main tab timestamp?